# Bounds on Fourier coefficients for a bounded decaying function

Tags: fourier-series, upper-lower-bounds

I have a single variable function $f(x)$ defined for $x\in[0,L]$. The actual form of $f(x)$ is not known, but I know that $f(x)$ is bounded (maximum value of $|f(x)|=C,$ say) and $f(L)=0$. Also it is infinitely differentiable. Examples of such functions are $a/(b+x)$ with $a,b>0$, $e^{-x}\cos x,$ etc.

Now I write the unknown $f(x)$ as a cosine series: $f(x)=a_0/2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos (n\pi x/L)$ in which $a_n=(2/L)\int_0^Ldx~f(x)\cos(n\pi x/L)$. I happen to know the value of $a_0$ by another independent (physical) argument.

I want to know if one may infer reasonably tight bounds on $a_n$ with this much information? One may of course do the following: $a_n\leq(2/L)\int_0^Ldx~|f(x)||\cos(n\pi x/L)|\leq(2C/L)\int_0^Ldx~|\cos(n\pi x/L)|\leq 2C.$ Can something better than this be done?

Comment: Do you have any bounds on the derivatives of $f$?

Comment: @Fabian Right now, no. But I know that all derivatives are bounded. Suppose I could get actual bounds on first derivative employing some heuristic argument, can I get a better answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important information is not only boundness of $f$ but the fact that it is infinitely differentiable. With this information, we can find the estimate
$$ a_n = \frac{2}{L} \int_0^L\!dx\,f(x) \cos(n\pi x /L) = -\frac{2}{n\pi} \int_0^L\!dx\, f'(x) \sin(n\pi x /L)$$
by integration by parts.

This shows, that given a bound $C_1$ on the first derivative, we have $$|a_n| \leq \frac{2 L C_1}{n \pi}\,.$$

Continuing this process, we obtain
$$ a_n = \frac{2 L \left[(-1)^{n} f'(L)-f'(0)\right]}{\pi ^2 n^2} - \frac{2L}{(\pi n)^2} \int_0^L\!dx\,f''(x)\cos(n\pi x /L).$$
With a bound $C_2$ on the second derivative, we have
$$|a_n|\leq \frac{2 L \left[(-1)^{n} f'(L)-f'(0)\right]}{\pi ^2 n^2} + \frac{2 L^2 C_2}{(\pi n)^2}.$$

These bounds are better then your original bound for large $n$.
Proceeding, we realize that if we have all derivatives bounded the Fourier coefficients $a_n$ decay faster than any power.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. Does your last statement "... decay faster than any power" mean that all $a_n$ would be zero if all derivatives of $f(x)$ were bounded? Also should it be $\sin$ instead of $\cos$ at the end of the first equation?

Comment: @Deep: no, it would mean that they typically decay exponentially with large $n$. (and fixed the typo)

Comment: @Fabian They will decay exponentially, but is it possible to know with which exponent? (Of course its module it will be lower than 1, but is it possible to get the exact constant?)

Comment: @user3141592: the exponent can be obtained by analytically continuing the function $f$ into the complex plane. It depends on the location (the imaginary part) of the singularity (pole or branch cut) closest to the real line.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Do you have any reference I can read or is there any term I can search in order to get more information about that?

Comment: @user3141592: this result should be in any decent book about Fourier or complex analysis. It relies on the fact that the integration contour can be shifted into the complex plane.