# Lower bound on Fourier coefficients for a $C^\infty$ function

Tags: fourier-series, upper-lower-bounds

This question is related to my earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633892/bounds-on-fourier-coefficients-for-a-bounded-decaying-function). The only difference is that I am now asking for a lower bound. (I wish I had asked this earlier.)

I have a single variable function $f(x)$ defined for $x\in[0,L]$. The actual form of $f(x)$ is not known, but I know that $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable and its derivatives are bounded and non-zero (so that constant function is ruled out, thanks to the comment by User8128).

Now I write the unknown $f(x)$ as a cosine series: $f(x)=a_0/2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos (n\pi x/L)$ in which $a_n=(2/L)\int_0^Ldx~f(x)\cos(n\pi x/L)$. I want to know if one may infer reasonably tight **lower** bound on $a_n$ (or at least a lower bound on $|a_n|$)? Preferably that lower bound is a function of $n$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You shouldn't expect a lower bound. If $f$ is constant than $a_n$ is zero for all $n > 0$.

Comment: @User8128 May be I should add that derivatives are non-zero. This is a function that arises in a physical problem and is never a constant function.

Comment: There is no slowest converging series of positive terms. Which implies there is no slowest converging series of squares. Every such series can be made into the coefficients of some Fourier series.